# How to load entire folder of xml files for configuration in Spring?

Tags: java, spring

Is there a way to tell Spring to look up for xml files with configuration (application context, beans, etc) in entire folder by specifying only the folder's name? I intend to use such an approach for quick module integration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<import resource="folder/*.xml" />
```